# Fetch unique values from different columns and paste in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I can fetch values unqiue values from one column (sheet1) and paste to another column (sheet2)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
    Set Sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = Sh1.Range("A1:A" & Sh1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set Sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Rng.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sh2.Cells(1, 1)
    Rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sh2.Range("A1"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

What I want to do is instead of only one a column I want to do for multiple column ( b , e,g) . How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You woud need to define the specific columns `ColumnList = Array("B", "E", "G")` and then use a loop to process each of them `For Each Col In ColumnList`.

Also I recommend to use meaningful variable names eg `wsInput` instead of `sh1` which makes your code much more human readable and therefore easier to maintain which results in less errors.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyUniqueDataOfColumns()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim ColumnList() As Variant
    ColumnList = Array("B", "E", "G")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    Dim Col As Variant
    For Each Col In ColumnList
        LastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

        If LastRow > 1 Then 'If data is found copy it
            Set CopyRng = wsInput.Range(wsInput.Cells(1, Col), wsInput.Cells(LastRow, Col))
            CopyRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsOutput.Cells(1, Col), Unique:=True
        Else 'If no data copy only header
            wsOutput.Cells(1, Col).Value = wsInput.Cells(1, Col).Value
        End If
    Next Col
End Sub
```

Comment: this give me error on line         CopyRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsOutput.Cells(1, Col), Unique:=True

Comment: thanks a lot mate it worked. How can i ignore header in this.

Comment: In `Cells(1, Col)` adjust the row count to start in row 2.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim Col As Long
    Set Sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    For Col = 1 To 3
        Set Rng = Sh1.Range(Sh1.Cells(1, Col), Sh1.Cells(65536, Col).End(xlUp))
        Rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sh2.Cells(1, Col), Unique:=True
    Next
End Sub
```

Col is the loop for the number of columns, and each column is copied for unique values. Change 1 and 3 as desired (e.g. columns B-F would be 2-6).

Comment: Will only work for continous columns but the OP asked for columns B, E, G. Also Different Excel formats have more rows than `65536` always use `Sh1.Rows.Count` instead.